# Подборка предобученных моделей нейронных сетей и библиотек

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

В этом вопросе собираются предобученные модели нейронных сетей. Просьба редактировать существующий ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [4chan & 8chan Word Embeddings](https://www.textgain.com/portfolio/8chanembeddings/)
  , [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.06946)
- [Online logistic regression creme-ml](https://github.com/creme-ml/creme)
- [Online logistic regression VowpalWabbit](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki)
- [Статьи с кодом](https://paperswithcode.com/)
- [Модель для создания музыки](https://github.com/Nikolay-Lysenko/rl-musician)
- [Multiple object tracking](https://github.com/Smorodov/Multitarget-tracker)
- [Библиотека для распознавания русской речи на Android и Linux без сети](https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=52171)
- [CMU Sphinx для распознования речи](https://cmusphinx.github.io/)
- [Julius для распознования речи](http://julius.osdn.jp/en_index.php)
- [RWTH ASR для распознования речи](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/rwth-asr/)
- [HTK (Hidden Markov Model Toolkit) для распознования речи](http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/)
- [Kaldi Speech Recognition Toolkit](https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi)
- [Модель для распознования людей в масках](https://github.com/broutonlab/face-id-with-medical-masks)
- [Pytorch pretrained models](https://github.com/Cadene/pretrained-models.pytorch)
- [pytorch hub](https://pytorch.org/hub/)